# What may cause a minidump disassembly to differ from the binary disassembly?

Tags: c++, disassembly, minidump

I have a minidump of a crash. At the point of the crash, there is some weird looking code that shouldn't ever run successfully. Something like:

```
call        AnObject::AFunction 
test        byte ptr [eax],cl
```

AnObject::AFunction is a member function that returns bool. So the result should be stored in eax as either 0 or 1. It does not make sense to dereference eax at this point.

I disassembled the corresponding binary and indeed, the code is different in this function:

```
call        AnObject::AFunction 
test        al, al
```

Why on earth would the minidump disassembly code be *different* from the actual binary disassembly code?

Comment: There is a real chance of stack corruption which can lead into this issue.

Comment: Wouldn't stack corruption only affect the stack frame and variables? Stack corruption shouldn't affect the read-only code.

Comment: Your code changed from `84 C0` to `84 08` - is it possible something overwrote your code while the program was running? Debuggers and other programs can do that.

Comment: Debuggers generally change the first byte of an instruction to 0xCC (INT 3 - Debugger Trap).